# SSL Key Decryption

Tags: php, ssl, https, wss

I am wondering if I can get the SSL Key given the following conditions:

```
Encrypted Text is known 
Decrypted Text is known
```

Any ideas on how I can create a program that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, of course this is not possible. If it were true, that would make SSL completely useless, as any computer can easily obtain the encrypted and clear text of any public HTTPS web site.